# structure or phrasal verb?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I think I understand what he wants to say, but cannot figure out the sentence structure or I just don't know such a phrasal verb.

"I thought of the Lake Como what I had thought of Lugano."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you write means "*I thought of Lake Como that which I had thought of Lugano*." Follow the link to find out about [cleft sentences](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv149.shtml).

Comment: Right. _What I had thought of Lugano_ (which looks like an embedded question) is actually what's called a *Headless Relative Clause*, and is equivalent to _that (thought) which I had thought of Lugano._ Headless relatives function as noun phrases, not as adjectives, because they have swallowed their coreferential head indefinite pronoun. Isn't English syntax fun?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Absolutely. One of the reasons I fell in love with the English language.

Comment: Oh, just noticed. This isn't actually a [Cleft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence); it's at best an aberrant [Pseudo-Cleft](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51466/which-form-of-a-verb-should-i-normally-use-after-what-you-have-done-is/51468#51468). There are other problems with the sentence, too, like article use and excessively complex structure.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Oops, I hadn't noticed the article use. I'll edit my answer. Thank you. I agree with your (more) accurate definition, too. Why don't you post your own answer? I'll be happy to upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

To figure it out, substitute  "I thought of the Lake Como" with "this was". E.g;

> This was what I had thought of Lugano

There is a kind of comparison between the lakes.

Answer (score 0):

One meaning of the phrasal verb *to think of* is *to have an opinion about*. So the sentence you quote means: *I had the same opinion about Lake Como as I did about Lugano.* The next sentence follows the same structure:

- I ate yesterday what I had eaten the day before.