# "What we are going to do is we are going to VERB"

Tags: phrases, expressions, redundancy

I see people using this redundant phrase a lot. How/why did this phrase become so popular and where is this used most frequently?

I personally hear this frequently in academia (STEM) on the east coast of the U.S. I wonder if this is also popular outside this bubble, perhaps even in the UK.

Maybe this is part of a class of expressions, i.e., "what I am eating is I am eating..." This one sounds weird though.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could list some actual usages of the phrase from real life academia...on the other hand, I am reminded of Popeye's signature phrase, "I yam what I yam. Dat's what I yam"

Comment: Is this distinct from "What we are going to do is we are going to..."? Or other variants? ("What we're gonna do...")

Comment: How do we get from "going to" to "gonna"?  Well, it is what I get when I say "going to" as quickly as I can.  Phonetically, the 'ng' sound is a the back of my throat and the 'to' sound is at the front, so I have to make a shift that slows me down.  "Gonna" can be said using just my tongue without moving my lips, which is faster.  If I then write it as I say it, "gonna" is a pretty good representation of the sound.  Many children get nagged by their parents and teachers not to do this.  Without the influence of class consciousness, it might even develop into a dialect.

Comment: I would say that, in most of the US, it's unremarkable.

Comment: Maybe ask at Movies & TV.  I have a vague memory of having seen this on a screen, and maybe that was the origin.

Answer (score 4):

The construction is one stage of the derivation of a [*Wh*-cleft](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51468/15299), aka Pseudo-Cleft.

- *We're gonna fix the sewer.*

is the original sentence, and then *Wh*-clefting (among other changes) inserts a *Wh*-word, a pro-verb *do*, and a dummy *is*  as fulcrum of cleavage

- *[**What** we're gonna **do**] **is** [we're gonna fix the sewer].*

Then [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/524673/15299) deletes the repeated *we're gonna*, leaving a normal *Wh*-cleft:

- *[What we're gonna do] is [fix the sewer].*

In the case of the example sentence in the question, conjunction reduction hasn't applied, leaving the intermediate structure. This is fine, since [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) is an optional rule.

All these sentences are grammatical, and they all mean the same thing.
Syntactic transformations don't change meaning,  only structure.

Comment: In saying they're 'fine', John, do you mean that none will grate on the ears of a fair section of society more than any other?

Comment: Like all variants, they vary. Among people and among contexts. Who knows what will grate on the ears of the ignorant, or the cognoscenti? Let them use earplugs.

Comment: Made of cake, perhaps.

Comment: They change more than structure. They also change tone.